# Please help with this wiring diagram

Tags: electrical

[image: Wiring Diagram]

I want to be able to control the chandelier's light (off and on) using the remote. My configuration is in the image above. I can only get the chandelier to turn on but can't get the remote function to work. It's called a "Universal On and Off Ceiling Fan Remote Control" model #99112 if that helps. On the Home Depot website, others have mentioned they can get a single light to work with this remote/receiver. Guidance is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use this specific product for this task?

Comment: No, it just happened to be the one recommended to me by a Home Depot employee

Comment: Are you OK with something whose receiver replaces your wall switch instead of the remote you have?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [installation guide](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/c7/c7d71778-b232-4f60-b346-4348d7ca3fcb.pdf):

- Connect the yellow wire from the receiver to the black wire from the fixture
- The blue wire from the receiver won't be used, so just cap it. (This would be connected to a blue wire (or possibly black with white stripe wire) if your fixture had a fan)
- Connect the black from the ceiling box to the black on the receiver
- Connect all the whites together
- And finally connect the grounds together